# Create heat map with three factors

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a dataset like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Taxa=rep(c("Ants","Birds"),each=4),
                 Predictor=rep(c("Area","Temp"),times=4),
                 Method=rep(c(1,1,2,2),times=2),
                 Importance=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1))
```

And I would like a heatmap in R like this:

[image]

Does anyone has a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `gt` package to color table cells:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Predictor", values_from = "Importance") %>% 
  group_by(Taxa) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE) %>% 
  data_color(columns = c("Area", "Temp"), colors = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help but it seems that the colour selection to the Importance doesn't work with larger datasets: "df <- data.frame(Taxa=rep(paste("Taxon",c(1:8),sep= ""),each=16), 
                 Predictor=rep(paste("Var",c(1:8),sep = ""),times=16),
                 Method=rep(c(rep(1,times=8),rep(2,times=8)),times=2),
                 Importance=rep(sample(1:8, 8, replace=F),times=16))"

Answer (score 1):

Not quite like the example you provided, but using `ggplot` we can use `facet_wrap()` to display the grouping by Taxa:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Taxa = rep(c("Ants", "Birds"), each = 4),
  Predictor = rep(c("Area", "Temp"), times = 4),
  Method = rep(c(1, 1, 2, 2), times = 2),
  Importance = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(
  x = as.character(Method),
  y = Predictor,
  fill = Importance
)) + geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Taxa) + xlab("Method")
```

[image]